# Upper bound for norm of matrix (cf. Example 2.7-7 in Erwine Kreyszig's book)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $A \colon = [\alpha_{ij}]_{m\times n}$ be a given $m \times n$ matrix of real numbers.

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be the norm space of all ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers with the norm defined as follows: 
$$\Vert x \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n} \colon= \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n \xi_j^2} \ \ \ \forall x \colon= (\xi_1, \ldots, \xi_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Let $\mathbb{R}^m$ be the norm space of all ordered $m$-tuples of real numbers with the norm defined as follows: 
$$\Vert y \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^m} \colon= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \eta_i^2} \ \ \ \forall y \colon= (\eta_1, \ldots, \eta_m) \in \mathbb{R}^m.$$

Let the operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be defined as 
$$T(x) \colon= Ax \ \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n;$$
where $x$ and $y$ are to be written as column vectors and $Ax$ denotes the usual matrix product. Of course, $T$ is linear.

Then, as Kryeszig has shown, $T$ is bounded with 
$$\Vert T \Vert \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_{ij}^2}.$$

What is $\Vert T \Vert$?

Here we are using the following definition for $\Vert T \Vert$: 
$$\Vert T \Vert \colon= \sup \left\{ \ \frac{\Vert T(x)\vert_{\mathbb{R}^m}}{\Vert x \Vert_{\mathbb{R}^n}} \ \colon \ x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \ x \neq \theta_{\mathbb{R}^n} \ \right\}. $$
Here $\theta_{\mathbb{R}^n} $ denotes the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is related with [the Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) and it is defined as
$$\|A\|_F =\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2}\;.$$
It can be proved that this norm is not induced by any vector norm, hence there does **not exist** a vector norm such that the following holds:

$$\|T\|_F = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}.$$

It's really easy to prove. An operator (matrix) norm, in order to be a norm induced by a vector norm, has to be $1$ for the identity operator:
$$\|I\| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|Ix\|}{\|x\|} = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac{\|x\|}{\|x\|} = 1.$$

The norm of the identity operator (matrix) is not unitary in Frobenius norm: $$\|I_n\|_F = \sqrt{n}.$$

Since $1 \ne \sqrt{n}$, this norm is not induced by any vector norm with the "sup" formula.

Comment: your answer is useful, but what is $\Vert T \Vert$ in our case? And, how to find it?

Comment: It depends on the coefficients of matrix $A$. Your example is rather abstract and we don't have an expression for those $a_{ij}$...